# Accidentally copied folder and files into a single file

Tags: batch-file, copy, dos, extract

An ms-dos backup batch file has copied all files and subfolders from a single folder into a single file on a usb stick. Is there any way we can extract theses files and folders from the single file that was created?

Comment: What command-line did you execute?

Comment: It was the equivilent to copy *.* c:\temp\test
The original script was to copy files into an existing folder but at some point that folder was deleted, which means copy made it's own file and copied all the files and folders into that file.

Comment: "copy . c:\temp\test" is invalid unless c:\temp\test exists and is a directory, which should work, so I'm not sure that's what you did.  Perhaps more like what I wrote below?

Comment: sorry, it should be copy star.star c:\temp\test, must have been removed. That command does work, try it for yourself. I should say that there are subfolder switches as well but the basic idea is the same, all files get melded into one.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way to extract individual files/folders from the combined large file (at least, not in an easy way); I hope you had NOT deleted the original files! I suggest you to use `XCOPY /I` instead of `COPY` that avoid this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you probably did was the equivalent of

```
copy f1.txt d:\backup\backupfile
copy f2.txt d:\backup\backupfile
copy f3.txt d:\backup\backupfile
```

which, since backupfile isn't a directory, copied all 3 files, successively, to the file d:\backup\backupfile.

Unfortunately, this means that first f1.txt was copied to that file, then f2.txt, then f3.txt.  Since each copy overwrote the file, I think you'll find that the contents of backupfile are equivalent to f3.txt (the last file that was backed up).   If you have already deleted f1 and f2.txt, then they're gone.